# Delphi 2007 - Systemwide Hot key is NOT "system-wide" if setting "MainFormOnTaskBar := True"

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a Delphi 2007 project that has run fine on Windos XP, Vista and "7" for years. It was an upgrade from Delphi 5 thus "MainFormOnTaskBar" was "false" by default (I never changed it in DPR). In this scenario, the system-wide hot key worked "system-wide" with following code in main form's OnCreate event handler.

```
HotKey_xyz := GlobalAddAtom('Hotkey_xyz');
if NOT RegisterHotKey(Self.Handle, HotKey_xyz, MOD_CONTROL, VK_F12) then
    ShowMessage('Unable to register Control-F12 as system-wide hot key') ;

(I have GlobalDeleteAtom() and UnregisterHotKey() in Form.OnDestroy as expected.)
```

Now, I need a Form to show its own button on Taskbar, so I set "Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := True" in DPR. This works as expected. However, this has the side-effect that Control-F12 does NOT work system-wide, it works ONLY IF my application has focus (so, it is NOT "system-wide" anymore.)

I have extensively searched the 'Net have found many articles regarding how/why "MainFormOnTaskBar" affects certain subform/modal form behaviors. However, I have found nothing regarding its effect on a "System-Wide Hot Key" issue that I describe above. I have tested and retested my application with MainFormOnTaskBar set to true and false while all else remains exactly the same. I can positively verify that the above described issue with System-wide hot key relates to MainFormOnTaskBar flag.

I will greatly appreciate any guidance regarding a work-around. I do need BOTH - a system-wide hot key AND a form with its own button on taskbar.

Thank You very much.

Comment: Can you duplicate it with a *new* project? I couldn't..

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. Can you post more code? (And possibly try changing `Self.Handle` to `Application.Handle` in the `RegisterHotkey` call in the meantime? The `WM_HOTKEY` message will still get to your form, because the application's message handler doesn't do anything with it; it will be sent on to your form just like usual.)

Comment: @KenWhite: if `Application.Handle` is used to register the hot key, then the `WM_HOTKEY` messages WILL NOT be directed to the TForm, directly or indirectly. They will be directed to `TApplication` instead, so to catch those messages you have to use the `TApplication.OnMessage` event and/or the `TApplication.HookMainWindow()` method.

Comment: @Remy, that's not true. The message goes to `TApplication.WndProc`, which has nothing to deal with it. It's then dispatched to other windows. (I can positively confirm this, because I have a component that uses this method to route `WM_HOTKEY` messages to whatever form it's placed on via `Application.Handle`.) Your answer (with `AllocHWnd`) looks good, though.

Comment: Adding following comment for others who may run into the same issue. Thanks to this community, my problem is solved. Following is my best guess as to why I ran into this issue.  I have used the same code for years without any problems. May be, setting "MainFormOnTaskBar := True " causes Main Form's handle to be destroyed and recreated at some point AFTER Form.OnCreate() is called. Obviously, this was not happening UNTIL I changed the code in DPR. Once again, thanks to everyone who responded to my message.

Comment: I had problems with system-wide keys when 'Handle' was pointing to the wrong window (I moved the code from the main window to a different window)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`TApplication.MainFormOnTaskbar` has no effect on system-wide hotkeys at all.  I can positively confirm that.  I am able to receive `WM_HOTKEY` messages regardless of what `MainFormOnTaskbar` is set to, regardless of whether the app is focused or not, etc.  So whatever you are seeing is not what you think is happening.

Most likely, the Form's `Handle` is simply being recreated behind your back after you have called `RegisterHotKey()`, so you lose the `HWND` that would receive the `WM_HOTKEY` messages.  Instead of using the `OnCreate` event, you should override the Form's `CreateWindowHandle()` and `DestroyWindowHandle()` methods instead to ensure the hot key is always registered for the Form's current `HWND` no matter what happens to it (you should always do that whenever you tie any kind of data to the Form's `Handle`), eg:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    HotKey_xyz: WORD;
    procedure WMHotKey(var Message: TMessage); message WM_HOTKEY;
  protected
    procedure CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure DestroyWindowHandle; override;
  end;

procedure TForm1.CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  HotKey_xyz := GlobalAddAtom('Hotkey_xyz'); 
  if HotKey_xyz <> 0 then
    RegisterHotKey(Self.Handle, HotKey_xyz, MOD_CONTROL, VK_F12);
end;

procedure TForm1.DestroyWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  if HotKey_xyz <> 0 then
  begin
    UnregisterHotKey(Self.Handle, HotKey_xyz);
    GlobalDeleteAtom(HotKey_xyz);
    HotKey_xyz := 0;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMHotKey(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  ...
end;
```

A better option is to use `AllocateHWnd()` to allocate a separate dedicated `HWND` just for handling the hot key messages (then you can use the `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` events again), eg:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    HotKey_xyz: WORD;
    HotKeyWnd: HWND;
    procedure HotKeyWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HotKeyWnd := AllocateHwnd(HotKeyWndProc);
  HotKey_xyz := GlobalAddAtom('Hotkey_xyz'); 
  if HotKey_xyz <> 0 then
    RegisterHotKey(HotKeyWnd, HotKey_xyz, MOD_CONTROL, VK_F12);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if HotKey_xyz <> 0 then
  begin
    UnregisterHotKey(HotKeyWnd, HotKey_xyz);
    GlobalDeleteAtom(HotKey_xyz);
    HotKey_xyz := 0;
  end;
  if HotKeyWnd <> 0 then
  begin
    DeallocateHWnd(HotKeyWnd);
    HotKeyWnd := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.HotKeyWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_HOTKEY then
  begin
    ...
  end else
    Message.Result := DefWindowProc(HotKeyWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;
```

Comment: +1 for the `AllocHWnd` code example alone. Nice - I've never seen it done like that before. I'll be marking this for future reference.

Comment: @Remy: Thank you so much for: CreateWindowHandle() and DestroyWindowHandle() methods - that did the trick. So, Can't thank you enough. I will explore "AllocateWnd()" - I need more education on that one! I wanted to UP-Vote your answer but Stack Overflow says I don't have enough "reputations" to do so.

Comment: @All: Thanks to everyone who commented and took time to test my contention that MainFormOnTaskBar flag was the culprit - I stand educated that it is not. Again, I very much appreciate this communities support and willingness to help.